# Lowdb - push data into an array inside another array

Tags: node.js, discord

I'm basicaly trying to do a inventory for each user, to do this i used `Lowdb` to help me out with the data.
My current structure is like this:

```
 {
  "users": [
    {
    "id": "450453034724491266",
    "tag": "Briggs#4992",
    "inventory": [
      {"itemID": "1320488779", "rarity": "rare"},
      {"itemID": "1674364779", "rarity": "common"},
    ]
  },
    {
     "id": "272659147974115328",
     "tag": "Zytekaron#0572",
     "inventory": [
      {"itemID": "1320488779", "rarity": "rare"},
      {"itemID": "1674364779", "rarity": "common"},
     ]
    }
  ]
}
```

what I have in mind is something like

```
//get 'users', find the id and then write inside the inventory array (which i dont know how to)
db.get('users')
.find({ id: 'id' })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tested this code snippet and it is working perfectly.

```
// Get your user
let inventory = db
    .get('users')
    .find({ id: '272659147974115328' })
    .get('inventory')
    .value();

// Do something to your user's inventory
inventory.push({ itemID: '9999999', rarity: 'common' });

// Update the user with the modified inventory

db.get('users')
    .find({ id: '272659147974115328' })
    .assign({ inventory })
    .write();
```

Comment: Thanks!! Sorry for replaying so late though

Comment: No problem! Thanks for following up :)

Answer (score 0):

two quick answers:

get the object by the id. modify->replace-save;

you can do an assign like: object.assign({inventory:[newInventory]}).write();

where object is your user you just got from the db.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to use `push` directly:

```
db
.get('users')
.find({ id: '272659147974115328' })
.get('inventory')
.push({ itemID: '9999999', rarity: 'common' })
.write();
```